# Number of answers

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose that teacher prepares  $5$ objective types of questions from which $4$ have to be answered. We should find the number of ways this tests could be answered if the first two have $3$ choices and the last three  has $4$ choices. My idea  is that because we have to answer $4$, number of ways of $4$ out of $5$ is $5!/(5-4)!$ because  the order of tests matters, some has  three choices and another has  $4$  choices. Also,  first two can be  answered $2*3=6$ ways and last three  $3*4=12$ ways, so in total $6*12=72$ ways, but how it will help us? Please see this question for more detail

http://www.greguide.com/Free-GRE-Practice-Tests/Problem-Solving-GRE-Practice-Test-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let questions with 3 choices be type A

Let questions with 4 choices be type B

2 possibilities $$2A + 2B $$ , $$ 1A + 3 B $$

**WAYS TO SELECT QUESTIONS :**

CASE 1 : $$2A + 2B $$  => No of ways of selecting questions = $2C2 * 3C2$ = $3$

CASE 2 : $$ 1A + 3 B $$ => No of ways of selecting questions = $2C1 * 3C3$ = $2$

**WAYS TO ANSWER QUESTIONS :**

CASE 1 : $$2A + 2B $$ => number of ways of answering = $3*3*4*4$  = $144$

CASE 2 : $$ 1A + 3 B $$ => number of ways of answering = $3*4*4*4 $ = $192 $

so answer is $ 3* 144 + 2*192 $

= $816$

Comment: i did not understand,please help me

Comment: Hi ,the way is to first select questions and then answer. So u need 4 questions .It cannot neither be 4 of type A nor 4 of type B , so this is ruled out . the other possible cases are the ones in answer . for each case select questions and then answer .Selecting questions is out of n questions of type A we select r . Then for that r we are going to answer . see number of choices  , so now we select one choice from this . so this answering can be done in a number of ways . multiply both to get total combination. so for each case $Question selecting ways \times Question answering ways $.

Comment: no no i am asking different one,there we should  should determine number of $4$ from $5$ right?

Comment: Hi @dato sorry for delayed response . I am at office .I would definitely clear your doubt tonight (7 hrs from now )

Comment: Ya that is inculded in 2A+ 2B , 1A + 3B , as here the total number is 4 in each case . Ya normally we do 5C4 but here within these 4  we have different types within them. Had all been similar we would have very well done it as 5C4 .

Comment: i have clarified it using internet,so it means that if there is  $1*A+3*B$,it means that total way would be $3*4*4*4=192$

Comment: Ya A has 3 choices B has 4 choices . so A can be answered in 3 ways . so B can be answered in 4 ways

Comment: if were would be $2A$+$2$B,then $3*3*4*4=144$ so total would be $192+144=316$

Comment: You have forgotten the number of ways question was selected .

Comment: is it right?then i have another question, why we are multiplying?

Comment: we select the questions "AND" answer it ."AND" is multiplying

Comment: thanks very much,i have understood everything

Comment: Good . Happy learning .